# Firebase tokens expiration and best practice for handling refresh tokens

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am currently using Firebase on a client application (Cordova based mobile app) using the firebase user authentication methods on the client:

- **signInWithEmailAndPassword**
- **FacebookAuthProvider**

From my current understanding and experience with the sessions expiring:

"*Authentication sessions don't expire with Firebase login. But the ID token will have to be refreshed hourly, to keep access to the services.*"

I assume this would mean I should just write a background process method that runs every 59 minutes and run the firebase method:

**firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true)** 
// true indicates according to firebase docs to forceRefresh regardless of the current tokens expiration.

I am just looking to make sure that I have wrapped my head around this.

I'm going with something simple like this... this should probably do the trick:

```
  let firebaseTokenRefresh = setInterval(function(){
     console.log('running firebase token refresh...');
     // true = forceRefresh
     firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true); 
  }, 3540000); // 59 minutes firebase token refresh (1 hr expiration)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to proactively refresh the token (it is too expensive to do so). Anytime you need an ID token, you just call `user.getIdToken()`. This will either return the cached unexpired token or refresh it if the current one is expired. You can call that anytime you are sending an authenticated request to your server.
If you are using Firestore or Realtime database, they will automatically refresh the token for you anytime they need on. You can listen to token updates via `auth.onIdTokenChanged()` listener.

Comment: That's not correct, they do expire after 1 hour and if you used the result from getIdToken and stored the token in prefs so you could send it to your API when you need a request, sending that same token to them after 1 hour without refreshing it first, will cause their firebase calls to return "expired token" so they will return 401 Unauthorized to you.

Comment: Of course they expire. They are JWTs with an expiration time. Read the answer. You don't store them in locally. They are already stored and managed for you. You call the official API when you need one. It refreshes them for you.

Comment: please any link

Comment: Then, how can I get a token with a custom expiration time?

Comment: This is such a fantastic answer. I wish the official documentation was this clear. Would have saved me a lot of time (and code).

Comment: This is WRONG. fb.auth().user will be null after the token has expired. So you cannot call getIdToken on it after token has already expired.