# firebase.auth() - How to get token expiration time in client?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Although `onIdTokenChanged`is documented to include "token refresh events", it is not called when token expires.
I save it in cookie so I can't call `getIdToken`on any request like it is recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52879989/firebase-tokens-expiration-and-best-practice-for-handling-refresh-tokens)

How can I get the expiration time? I found in the `user` object returned by `onIdTokenChanged`:

```
stsTokenManager: {
        apiKey: "AIz ...",
        refreshToken: "AEu4IL3Uhz .....",
        accessToken: "eyJhbGc .....",
        expirationTime: 1585054658000
    }
```

So I extracted the expiration time from there and it works. But it feels like a hack, not a real, stable solution. Any suggestion? I found nothing on official documentation but the info is there, so it has to be something.

Comment: The SDK is not known to fail to refresh tokens as they expire, except when there is a lack of network connectivity.  It should work fine.  You shouldn't have to do anything special to refresh a token.  If you think the Firebase SDK is at fault for not refreshing, and you're able to reproduce the issue, then I suggest filing a bug with Firebase support.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: Thanks Doug, but I understood that not calling `onIdTokenChanged` when the token expires it is standard functionality, not bug. Also discussed here, in stackoverflow, in the link I posted.
Indeed, if I use `getTokenId(true)` (forced refresh) it works with out problems. The cb is not called on expiration.

Comment: No, the documentation makes it clear that onIdTokenChanged will be called whenever the token is refreshed.  That's that way it works, and it works that way for me. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onidtokenchanged

Comment: That's true and it was my understanding as well. However it is not called on expiration. I did test it - even if it is difficult as you have to wait for 1h.

Not sure how to reproduce. If I reset the token via a simple call to `getTokenId(true)` it works without problems, as I said already.

Comment: In can confirm this.. it does not refresh when token expired.. Also it does not auto get a new token when it's expired.. you need to call gettokenid... But is it "best practice" to continuesly refresh the token by calling it through `setInterval` for instance?

Comment: Not really, no.
They recommend to send with getIdToken() on every request. It is updated when required.
But that is difficult and redundant.
I kept the hack, I find out from server side when it expires and I refresh it.